# Get number of likes on facebook page

Tags: javascript, sdk, token

i want to get count of likes on a facebook page using javascript SDK. i am using...

```
FB.api(
    "/pageID/likes",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

returns:
{message: "An access token is required to request this resource.", type: "OAuthException", code: 104,…}

How to get access token? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Take a look at the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This link](https://smashballoon.com/custom-facebook-feed/access-token/) can help you. When you use an API you always need to have a token to be allowed to request it. Facebook [have a platform](https://developers.facebook.com/) to sign-in and get a token. Facebook have a [full documentation here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/).

Comment: No problem ! If it solved your question then mark my answer as the good one :)